# Python Read Directory And Output to CSV

Tags: python, csv, file, output, scandir

I am just trying to read a directory and out put the file names to a csv.  The directory read works fine.  It is when I try to write to the csv that I am getting this error.

line 148, in _dict_to_list
wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

```
import os
import csv

path = 'F:\Production\FocusPoint'
filename = 'storage.csv'
fields = ['Name']

with os.scandir(path) as listOfEntries:
    for entry in listOfEntries:
        if entry.is_file():
            f = (entry.name)

with open(filename,'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames= fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `fields` is not a dictionary. So `csv.DictWriter` will not work. How about?

```
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
```